# Best practice authentication concept for realm atlas and aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, realm, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently using Realm via MongoDB Atlas in my (swift) app as a database and would like to use AWS S3 (via amplify?) to store data. However I'm trying to wrap my head around how to best setup the user authentication for S3.

At the moment I just use the e-mail & password authentication from MongoDB Atlas to log into the database.

Is the best way to use AWS Cognito and then login via a JWT authentication to MongoDB Atlas? I'm quite new to programming so I'm unfortunately not aware of a good concept here.

Any hints on how to do it or which concepts can be used would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Just curious - you have a perfectly good cloud storage service with Atlas including authentication. Why implement another service?

Comment: Because I don't know how I can manage authentications with AWS S3 at the same time. Is there an easier way on how users can log into my app and still have only access to only their data on S3? I'm probably not aware of the obvious solution ...

Comment: My question was why use a totally different service (S3) when you can store your data in MongoDB Realm Atlas and also have MongoDB Realm Atlas handle authentication. e.g. why use S3 at all?

Comment: Do you mean storing them in the DB via blob or Gridsf?

Comment: You can store anything in Atlas. Your front end is MongoDB Realm which optionally sync's to Atlas. MongoDB offers storage via Atlas and user authentication in one solution. See the [MongoDB Realm documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/). Using a single service may save a lot of time and make development and maintenance easier.

Comment: That's a good point but this way I cannot generate download links for e.g. images which would by cached by my applications and I cannot share a download link via e-mail if I need to share files with other users so I guess I'll still need S3. Do you know how and with which service I can generate a JWT with AWS?

Comment: You can do all of those things with MongoDB and [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)